# Is it possible to reproject KML using ESRI's Silverlight API?

Tags: kml, coordinate-system, arcgis-silverlight-api

My question is similar to [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15826/is-it-possible-to-reproject-kml-using-esris-javascript-api), but for Silverlight.

I need to reproject an entire KML file to NAD83, add it to the map with all the layers, symbology, etc. in tact.

Is there anyway to do this with the Silverlight API?

Answer (score 1):

In Silverlight, the KMLLayer has a [ProjectionService](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/silverlight-api/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources.KmlLayer~ProjectionService.html) parameter that you can bind to the GeometryService. [This example](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/samples/start.htm#AutoProjectGraphics) does something similar with a [GeoRSSLayer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/silverlight-api/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources.GeoRssLayer.html), and it should work the same with the [KMLLayer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/silverlight-api/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources.KmlLayer.html).